# Stop firefox extension from re-running its code every time its clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox-addon-webextensions

EDIT

I wasn't able to do this, I'm not sure if it's even possible. However, my problem was not being able to control or manage a state and I got around it by using the browser storage for extensions, it's not domain-based (unlike `localstorage`) and I think it's made for this specific purpose: `browser.storage.local` or `.sync`.

This has raised another issue though, in `React` the term `browser` isn't defined, and rightly so, the way to get around it is to add, at the start of your `JavaScript` file, this: `/* global browser */`.

That if you are working with `Firefox`, if you are making an extension for `Chrome` then just replace the word `browser` with `chrome`. This tells eslint (if you have it installed) to not break the execution when you build your app (ex: when running `yarn build`).

After building successfully, the term `browser` indeed becomes defined because the app at that point is an extension and no longer a regular web app or a web page.

Hope this helps anyone who might be having the same problem as me in the future.

Right now, I can't work with my extension as a regular web app because I can't `yarn start` it because it breaks when it reaches `browser`.local.storage, because `browser` is not defined but when I packaged it and run it as an extension, it works like a charm.

EDIT END

I'm making an extension for Firefox using React. I'm at the point where I want the extension to not execute all my code once again every time I click it, I'm not sure about this behavior (this is my first time making an extension) but from what I understand, every time the `popup` opens (you click on the extension icon) the whole code is being run anew.

Now I don't want this behavior because I'm showing some info in my extension from an API and I want to update that info each hour or so, but if my code runs anew every time the extension is clicked then I can never maintain a timer or any state (using `setTimeOut` or `setInterval`). Right now, every time I open the extension a new API call is being made and new info is being shown.

Is my approach wrong? can extensions do this even, not running their entire code every time they are clicked? what I can do about this?

This is my `manifest.json`:

```
{
    "name": "some name",
    "description": "some description",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1",
    "icons": {
        "16": "logo16.png",
        "32": "logo32.png"
    },
    "start_url": ".",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_title": "some title"
    },
    "browser_specific_settings": {
        "gecko": {
            "id": "someid"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll want to use a [background-script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension#background_scripts).

Comment: But if I change the state or the timer in the background script, how would React know about it? and re-render or work accordingly? can you please provide more details if possible?

Comment: What exactly is React doing? Which script is it running in? Are you just editing one specific page/website?

Comment: React is creating the extension (HTML, SCSS, JS), fetching the data from the API, and displaying it. I want to fetch new data after a fixed amount of time and display it in place of the old data but if everything is running anew a timer or a state can't be maintained unless you leave the extension (popup) open

Comment: Answers may on the rare occasion need "edit" sections, but posts never do. Please don't just slap new text that invalidates or changes parts of your original post at the start or end of your post: edit the post to properly reflect your current problem as a single cohesive post. Future visitors expect post that [properly explain the problem you're asking about](/help/how-to-ask), "edit" sections just make it harder to understand what the post is _really_ about.